# I can't ever get a weapon

Tags: unturned

I always try for weapons at first but even the tiniest shacks have 3 zeds in them and I always die before I can get anything. I have tried to fight one at a time but to get close to even one means that all 3 will come at me.

Answer (score 5):

This question is a little vague, so I'll answer with some general tips that may help.

Firstly, don't try to fight lots of zombies with your fists, get their attention, draw them away from the area, then run and grab what you want. If you're lucky you'll get a melee weapon and can kill off anyone following you.

Next, if you do have to fight them without a good weapon, try to get them in a line following you, then walk away from them attacking as you go (aka, walk backwards). You can usually kill a lot of them without getting hit. (Kind of a simple trick, but lots of people try to stand their ground, which just doesn't work against a horde)

Lastly, don't be afraid of running away. If there are too many zombies to fight, run. You can usually lose the majority of them as long as you keep going away from any towns/bases, then finish off the remaining ones.

It's also worth pointing out that this is a multiplayer game, if you can get a few friends together and work as a team you may also have better luck. (Though obviously that does also mean sharing the loot)

Comment: Also, In addition to DBS' answer, try starting off in Easy mode and working your way up. Avoid going to military locations, as the Zeds are stronger there with body armor and helmets. The police and firefighter Zeds are more optimal when starting in easier and have a good chance to drop police vests/handguns/fireaxes/clothing

Answer (score 0):

You might be playing an older version of unturned. Usually I try to sneak into a campsite or small area when i first spawn. I get a minimum of some clothing and a non-legit weapon(like a rake or an oar). And, do not try to fight more than 3 zeds with fists (or in fact any melee weapon!). Almost all melee weapons are not very effective! chainsaw exception. I usually start off with a nice sportshot or 20. shotgun:) So yeah, no one will judge you for sneaking in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Get a knife, sneak behind a zombie that is not near others, aim at the head (more damage dealt), kill it, takes what it drops, go to the next, etc. until there is no zombie left standing. There is strategy involved on choosing the attacking order.